# Change the series color indicator at the bottom of the chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I am using jfreechart to draw some charts, I wanted the chart bars to be custom colored so I followed tutorials and sample code mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952931/jfreechart-is-it-possible-to-change-the-bar-color) and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo.htm) link.

The issue with bar colors have been solved but now I can't change the series color indicator at the bottom of the chart as show in below pic.
[image]

Can someone please guide me as how to change their colors according to bars?

**Edit:**

```
class CustomRenderer extends BarRenderer
{
public Paint[] colors;

public CustomRenderer()
{
    this.colors = new Paint[] { Color.green, Color.red };
    /*
     * { Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.orange,
     * Color.cyan, Color.magenta, Color.blue };
     */
}

public Paint getItemPaint(final int row, final int column)
{
    // returns color for each column
    return ((column % 2 == 0) ? colors[0] : colors[1]);
}
}
//Code for creating the chart in main() method
DefaultCategoryDataset objDataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    objDataset.setValue(10, "POS", "one");
    objDataset.setValue(11, "NEG", "two");
    objDataset.setValue(8, "POS", "three");
    objDataset.setValue(12, "NEG", "four");


    final JFreeChart objChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "Top Ten Features", // Chart title
            "Features", // Domain axis label
            "POS and NEG value", // Range axis label
            objDataset, // Chart Data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
            true, // include legend?
            true, // include tooltips?
            false // include URLs?
            );


    final CategoryPlot categoryPlot = objChart.getCategoryPlot();
    CategoryItemRenderer renderere = new CustomRenderer();
    categoryPlot.setRenderer(renderere);
    final BarRenderer br = (BarRenderer) categoryPlot.getRenderer();
    br.setItemMargin(-1);

    final ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Demo", objChart);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows how you obtained the result shown.

Comment: @trashgod Code added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom `BarRenderer` overrides `getItemPaint()`, but it leaves the original `getLegendItem()` unchanged. The two methods need to be consistent. You can override `lookupSeriesPaint()` or, more generally, provide an alternate `DrawingSupplier`, as shown in the articles cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754801/230513).

Comment: Thank you so much, the DrawingSupplier solved the issue.